# PLSQL Trigger on a table with collection of columns

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table with a collections:
CS_PARAM_COLLECTION,

```
create table CS_TEST_WORK_DATA
(
  TRANS_ID    VARCHAR2(12) not null,
  TEST_ID    VARCHAR2(12),
  ITEMS       CS_PARAM_COLLECTION,
  ACTIVE      NUMBER default 1,
  UPDATE_USER VARCHAR2(8),
  UPDATE_DATE DATE
)
nested table ITEMS store as TEST_DATA
```

How can I create a trigger for these table collection columns.

Comment: Trigger to do what ? Specify it clearly. Preferably show us the code which you attempted.

Comment: Are you looking for the `on nested table` option? https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-9F06D45C-7C60-434E-A597-114A0C445671 or simply a trigger `before update of items`? https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-9F06D45C-7C60-434E-A597-114A0C445671